# Disable JS Photo Gallery ID information in URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using a javascript photo gallery that is set on a timer for a Wordpress site at work and every time the new photo is loaded it the change is updated in the URL. I want to disable this. For example, the page gets loaded and updates the URL with the gallery every 5 seconds.

```
www.example.com/gallery/#image-1

www.example.com/gallery/#image-2

www.example.com/gallery/#image-3
```

I know that isn't going to fly with the boss. Especially if we were to put a on the home.The photo gallery I am using is a plugin based from this http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/ and the plugin I am using is this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ad-gallery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the `update_window_hash: false` option parameter on gallery initialization?

http://adgallery.codeplex.com/documentation

From the screenshots there's seems to be a setting as a dropdown list in wordpress called "Windows hash"
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ad-gallery/screenshots/

Comment: I believe that is the answer I am looking for! But its not working right away. Something going on with wordpress where its not updating the javascript file. Maybe I have to unload and load the plugin again?

Comment: Have you tried the "Windows hash" settings in the plugin settings. There's a default dropdown that is by default set to "Yes" It should be "No" of course :)

Comment: Thanks! sometimes they make this thing _too_ easy :)